# Fibered product of varieties: is $(Y \times Y) \times_{X \times X} X \cong Y \times_X Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a projective variety over field $k$ and $Y \to X$ is a map. Set $X \times X$ to be fibered product over $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$. Then $Y \times Y$ is a variety over $X \times X$ and $X$ is also variety over $X \times X$ via the diagonal map. Is it true that
$$
(Y \times Y) \times_{X \times X} X \cong Y \times_X Y?
$$

It seems to be true for affine varieties and then we can try to glue, but perhaps there are better/shorter proofs of this fact.

Comment: Over which base is your product $Y \times Y$?

Comment: Over $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$.

Comment: @Alex did my answer solve the question for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the fibre product in a category $\mathscr C$ is an object representing the functor $$T \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(T,X)\times_{\operatorname{Hom}(T,Z)}\operatorname{Hom}(T,Y),$$
given $f:X \longrightarrow Z$ and $g:Y \longrightarrow Z$. 
By the Yoneda Lemma, we only need to show the required equivalence in the category of sets.

Comment: This answer, while consisting entirely of true statements, seems incomplete to me: is this provided as a hint? Are you leaving the final details to the reader? If this is the case, saying so in the answer would be beneficial.

Comment: @KReiser You‘re right, the answer is incomplete. But it isn‘t hard to check that the statement is true for sets.

Comment: My point is that adding the words "hint", "I leave the final details to the reader", and/or "one can check the statement for sets" would reduce confusion about this answer, and is generally a good practice to fall in to in the case when one intentionally provides an answer of this form.

Comment: @KReiser I‘ve edited my answer.